# Happy & Alex - Preventing the lookahead from affecting parser-lexer communication

Tags: parsing, haskell, compiler-construction, happy, alex

I am currently writing the parser for a compiler of a toy language 
using Happy & Alex. Since some form of optional layout is required I have to change
Alex's state before matching the `block` non-terminal. Unfortunately
it seems that the lookahead token required by Happy is read before
I have the chance to change Alex's state.

Here is a small snippet demonstrating the problem:

```
funcDef : header localDefs block
                          ^ I have to change alex's state 
                            before the underlying lexer
                            starts reading the block tokens.
```

Is there a common approach to this problem ?

Comment: How do you know where a block starts? I presume that `localDefs` is not self-terminating, so there must be some lexical feature that you can use to know where the block starts. Could you possibly elucidate a bit?

Comment: @rici The block is either surrounded by begin/end keywords or otherwise is indentation based. It is basically defined as either begin stmts+ end or stmts autoend. The lexer needs to be notified that a begin is missing in order to produce an autoend when it detecteds an identation change. The whole approach feels very hacky there has to be a better way.

Comment: I just solved this _exact_ problem two weeks ago. Didn't think anyone else would run across it.

Comment: @Alec eagerly waiting for details!

Comment: I'll wait to see what @alec writes, but my approach would be either to make the newline visible to the parser, in which case the lexer change can be done *before* the trigger token, or to handle it all in the lexer. Both are a bit hacky but so is the syntax :) Contrast python's use of colon.

Comment: @rici Please do post your solution - I would be very interested to see what else is possible. In my case, I was stuck with a lexer that I couldn't really change (I wanted it to behave like the reference implementation), so I instead ended up doing backflips in the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a threaded lexer (so Happy and Alex are running in the same monad). The trick I used when faced with a similar problem is to make an empty production rule that you slip into your rule.

```
changeAlexState :: { () }
  : {- empty -} {%% \tok -> changeAlexState *> pushTok tok }

funcDef : header localDefs changeAlexState block
```

Then, you need to add to your monad some state to support `pushTok :: Token -> P ()` (where `P` is your lexing/parsing monad) and make sure you always pop that token when when you are lexing. What `%%` does is [documented here](https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-monads.html#sec-lexers).

> `n  :  t_1 ... t_n          {%% <expr> }`
>
> ... The type of `<expr>` is the same [still `Token -> P a`], but in this case the lookahead token is actually discarded and a new token is read from the input. This can be useful when you want to change the next token and continue parsing.

I mentioned I did something similar not long ago. [Here is my "empty" rule](https://github.com/harpocrates/language-rust/blob/dbd63a6961bd609973b4ac075b11bff96d4b3cea/src/Language/Rust/Parser/Internal.y#L288-L299), [here is an example use of it](https://github.com/harpocrates/language-rust/blob/dbd63a6961bd609973b4ac075b11bff96d4b3cea/src/Language/Rust/Parser/Internal.y#L446), [here is where my pushing function is defined](https://github.com/harpocrates/language-rust/blob/master/src/Language/Rust/Parser/ParseMonad.hs#L123-L127) and [here is where I "pop" tokens](https://github.com/harpocrates/language-rust/blob/master/src/Language/Rust/Parser/Lexer.x#L1223). Let me know how it goes!